# sending user-defined structure using WM_COPYDATA message

Tags: c++, winapi

How can i send my structure to other application and recieve it using WM_COPYDATA message?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of this is explained by MS at [Using Data Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Is there anything missing in that example?

Comment: Thanks for that - just what I needed. :)

Comment: Can you please copy&paste the relevant bits to the answer? Links tend to rot over time, even Microsoft ones.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you use `SendMessage` and not `PostMessage`, since this is the only way to force Windows to synchronize the buffer transfer!